# bootstrap into luma extended theme - magento2

Tags: magento2, css, less, magento2.0.8

I created theme that extend luma. I have integrated bootstrap into magento using this [link](http://cedcommerce.com/blog/using-bootstrap-in-magento-2-0/)  after that product detail page and page header alignment are not nice. Due to commonalities between these two framework - bootstrap css and luma/adaptive css there's quite a bit of collusion happening, causing confusion and odd behavior.

Bootstrap is responsive web design, Luma use adaptive web design.

is this good way to integrate bootstrap into luma extended theme?

I'm looking expert suggestions to what are the things I need to concern If I integrate bootstrap into luma extended theme.

Comment: Try this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/how-to-develop-theme-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-magento-2

Comment: Example of porto theme `\magento\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`
`<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <css src="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <script src="jquery.js" />
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    </head>
</page>`

Comment: thanks guys! my question is not about how to add bootstrap. after added the page looks weird. how you guys are overcome this behavior? if I need to override bootstrap css I need to do lot of place so I thought it would not be a great solution.