# How to use bootstrap in my custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css, less

In my extended LUMA theme , how to integrate Bootstrap JS and CSS .

So I can make my CMS page's layout on Bootstrap grid .

Already seen few post here : [How to develop theme using twitter bootstrap in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/how-to-develop-theme-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-magento-2)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your extended theme path ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop theme using twitter bootstrap in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/how-to-develop-theme-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-magento-2) and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155064/bootstrap-into-luma-extended-theme-magento2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add Bootstrap this way, follow below steps

1) Place your JS and CSS at below location

> /app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/web/css
>
> /app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/web/js

2) Call files in your **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

add these line of code

```
<css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

3) Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

more you can check here related to css https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187029/54588

**Note:** This solution doesn't work with Magento 2.2.3 and above

Comment: I am getting big error like Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(t,e,n){"use strict";function i(t,e){for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var i=e[n];i.enumerable=i.enumerable||!1,i.configurable=!0,"value"in i&&(i.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(t,i.key,i)}}function s(t,e,n){return e&&i(t.prototype,e),n&&i(t,n),t}function r(){return(r=Object.assign||function(t){for(var e=1;e<arguments.length;e++){var n=arguments[e];for(var i in n)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,i)&&(t[i]=n[i])}return t}).apply(this,arguments)}e=e&&e.hasOwnProperty("default")?..

Comment: I couldn't understand this way, are you using extended theme and which your mage version ?

Comment: Magento 2.2.4. I am using custom theme . I am using bootstrap 4.

Comment: okay bootstrap 4 doesn't work this way, there are some bugs ... you need another way for that,, you post question for this ...and I will give you detailed ans of adding bootstrap for in latest magento , I added BS4 in 2.2.3 and should work for you as well

Comment: I have posted question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228063/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-in-magento-2-theme

Comment: @ManojDeswal Do you have any idea or any documents you know about Adobe XD design to Magento Commerce custom theme. my port https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/327041/57334