# How to apply Custom CSS on magento 2 checkout page(shipping and checkout)

Tags: magento2, checkout, jquery, knockoutjs

i have added two fields in my magento 2 checkout at shipping address tab.
My fields are check boxes and and i want to add some css to those check boxes therefore i have added custom `css` file but as i observer css gets applied after the page load.
Magento checkout is totally based on knockout js and other dependencies that why my `css` is not getting applied.
i have added a `hook.js` and that `js` file is getting applied.
i have also tried to add `Css` using jQuery.

```
        $("[name='shippingAddress.custom_attributes.displaynewsfeed']").css("padding-left","20%");
        $("[name='shippingAddress.custom_attributes.displayreceipt']").css("padding-left","20%");
```

But this is not getting applied so i have tried another method  in `jQuery` which delayed the function for 2 seconds its working but its not acceptable.
Is there any solution where i can add CSS withing the form load not after some seconds or before Form load.

Small Help will be Greatly Appreciated.
Thanks in Advanced :)

Comment: Check this out --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199962/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-css-class-in-checkout-shipping-address-form/199996

Comment: so you want to add CSS in checkout page?

Comment: do you have url

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use css for this? (add to your theme):

input[name='shippingAddress.custom_attributes.displaynewsfeed'] {
padding-left:20%
}

input[name='shippingAddress.custom_attributes.displayreceipt'] {
padding-left:20%
}

Comment: If i add custom css to  my  theme's css files will it solve my problem.
And will that css will apply all the magento 2 checkout fields load via knocoutn js and ajax