# In Magento 2, Can we use bootstrap 3 on Ves Need theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

Is that fine to use Bootstrap on Magento 2?.

Comment: Yes you can use bootstrap in your magento2 theme. You can refer following link for some insight..  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195508/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-my-custom-theme

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Will review and get this done ....

Comment: @ Ejilarasan J Please upvote the solution if it works fr you so that others are also benefit from it

Comment: @suragr I have upvoted your comment on Feb 22 itself.