# How to convert Adobe XD design to Magento 2 Custom Theme?

Tags: magento-enterprise, rwd, design-packages

I have Adobe XD Design, how to apply as a custom theme, my parent theme Default, how to apply the files. I am using Magento Enterprise Edition.
Note: Any basic docs welcome

Comment: I do not think such a feature is available

Comment: @AmitBera Yes i agree, Adobe XD have a feature like export,  we can export HTML, CSS files, i am created custom theme parent theme Default, how to incorporate my HTML design into Magento 2. where i need to work for designing Home page.

Comment: and where i need to place my CSS, i know basic CSS work but how to include my external CSS into Magento 2. I am using Magento Commerce.

Comment: I have a single page HTML design of Home Page, any docs available for how to create Magento home page in the custom theme.